# create a chart.js point dataset from json

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I am trying to create a line plot from the json response from a webApi. I would like to create a time point dataset which looks like below:

```
var adddata = {     
    datasets: [{
                label: "a",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",               
                fill: false,
                data: [{
                    x: newDateString(0),
                    y: 22
                }, {
                    x: newDateString(2),
                    y: 25
                }, {
                    x: newDateString(4),
                    y: 12
                }, {
                    x: newDateString(5),
                    y: 22
                }],
            }, {
                label: "b",
                backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,0.5)",                   
                fill: false,
                data: [{
                    x: newDate(0),
                    y: 34
                }, {
                    x: newDate(1),
                    y: 22
                }, {
                    x: newDate(4),
                    y: 2
                }, {
                    x: newDate(5),
                    y: 13
                }]
            }]
    };
```

Now if I have a json which looks like:

```
{"Values":{"2018-01-17 09:24:34":"0","2018-01-17 09:24:31":"0","2018-01-17 09:24:33":"0","2018-01-17 09:24:35":"0"}}
```

Would it be possible to create a data set defining individual points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse your JSON string and transform resulting json object to dataset like below:

```
var json_str = '{"Values":{"2018-01-16 09:24:34":"10","2018-01-16 19:24:31":"5","2018-01-17 09:24:33":"8","2018-01-18 09:24:35":"9"}}'
var json = JSON.parse(json_str);

var data = [];
for (var d in json.Values) {
    console.log(d, json.Values[d]);
    data.push({
        x : new Date(d),
        y : json.Values[d]
    })
}
var dataset = {
    label : "c",
    backgroundColor : "rgba(0,0,255,0.5)",
    borderColor : 'green',
    fill : false,
    data : data
};
// add to existing datasets
adddata.push(dataset);
```

So this is the result: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/mfvc9p9x/